# PayPal API permissions request takes user to PayPal home page

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I am using the [PayPal Permissions SDK](https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-dotnet) (Classic/NVP) to seek authorisation for third party payments.

The first time someone clicks on my button that redirects them to PayPal to login and authorise the request they get end up at the PayPal home page. If they go back and click my button again, it works this time and takes them to the right PayPal page.

Here is my code:

```
RequestPermissionsRequest rp = new RequestPermissionsRequest();
rp.scope = new List<string>();
rp.scope.Add("EXPRESS_CHECKOUT");
rp.callback = "my return url here";
rp.requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
RequestPermissionsResponse rpr = null;
PermissionsService service = new PermissionsService(PayPalClassicHelpers.Configuration.GetAcctAndConfig());
rpr = service.RequestPermissions(rp);
Response.Redirect("https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=" + rpr.token);
```

This redirects them to the PayPal URL:

```
https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=***rpr.token value***
```

But the first time they end up here:

```
https://www.paypal.com/us/home
```

Looking at the request and response headers, the first time I see this:

1. GET: https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=***
2. Response: HTTP/2.0 200 OK
3. Various CSS, JS and image requests
4. POST: https://www.paypal.com/auth/validatecaptcha
5. Response: HTTP/2.0 302 Found
   Location: /webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=***
6. GET: https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=***
7. Response: HTTP/2.0 302 Found
   Location: https://www.paypal.com/home

On subsequent requests there is no POST to `https://www.paypal.com/auth/validatecaptcha`.

I have tried this on a few networks and computers and it is always the same.

Has anyone experienced this and know of the cause and a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use '?' symbol after the webscr.

For example, change

`https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=` to

`https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=`

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I can't believe I didn't spot that myself in all this time. I don't understand why it would not work the first time but would work the second time, but it's working every time now I have made this change!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I have experienced the same issue when testing and debugging my code for PayPal recurring billing.

This is, most of the times in my case is because user is already logged in with other account and PayPal saved some cookies in the browser.

This might be the saved cookies issue and various accounts often used during development, such as sandbox seller and sandbox buyer.

Do check that and see if issues persist.

Again These are just my experiences and if your real users are actually experiencing this in production app then it might be something else completely.

Comment: I think I had similar issues when testing due to using different test accounts. But this time, on the live PayPal, it seems to be happening to everyone. I have just tested now after completely clearing browser data and it still does the same thing for some reason. Fortunately it works the second time, but it is difficult explaining to users to try and do it twice.